# Показ Aвmob межстраничного баннера при выходе

Tags: java, android, admob

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить такую задачу. Есть приложение, при выходе из него нужно показывать admob межстраничный баннер.

Делаю это так:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            });
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);
            return true;
        }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}`
```

При этом объявление показывается, но после его закрытия пользователь остаётся в приложении, нужно же чтобы если он закрыл объявление то произошёл выход из приложения. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дык, по правилам Гугла, рекламу **Запрещено** отображать при выходе из приложения ?

[Недопустимые способы размещения межстраничных объявлений](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=ru&ref_topic=2745287)

Answer (score 1):

должно быть событие вызываемое после закрытия объявления, и тогда закрывать или можешь просто закрывать приложение по таймеру, т.е. установил таймер с функции выхода через н секунд и включил показ объявления